# vb .net to launch Civil 3D without starting file

Tags: vb.net, autocad

I am creating a VB .NET application that will launch Civil 3D with different profiles.  I am having issue launching the application w/ parameters without a startup file.

```
    Dim desProf As String
    desProf = "<< C3D_Imperial >>"
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo

    p.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2022\acad.exe"
    p.Arguments = " /ld C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2022\AecBase.dbx "
    p.Arguments = "/p " & desProf & " /product C3D /language en-US"
    p.UseShellExecute = True
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    Process.Start(p)
```

The code results in an AutoCAD Message stating:  "Cannot file the specified drawing file.  Please verify that the file exists."

If I just use: Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2022\acad.exe")
I can get AutoCAD to start w/o prompting the drawing file is missing.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You’re overwriting your first set of arguments with the second. Try

```
p.Arguments = p.Arguments & "/p " & desProf & " /product C3D /language en-US"
```

Also, are you sure you need the << and >> characters?

Comment: The << and >> are part of the profile that needs to load the program.  They are standard in the installation.

Tried your suggestion and It's still giving me the missing file error.

Comment: Can you launch from a Windows shortcut with these parameters (hard code the desProf string)? That will tell you if you have the command line parameters correctly set.

Comment: Yes.  The default application shortcut is where I got the parameters from.

Comment: I think I’ve spotted the problem. You have spaces in your path names. You need to wrap names with embedded spaces inside “ marks.

Answer (score 0):

@SteveTodd, you are correct.  I fought with it for an hour and got it working.  Here is the final code:

```
p.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2022\acad.exe"
p.Arguments = " /ld ""C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2022\AecBase.dbx"" /p 
  " & desProf & " /product C3D /language en-US"
p.UseShellExecute = True
Process.Start(p)
```